# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() - can't loop through two arrays

Tags: php, json, steam-web-api

My code should convert "defindex" from array_inv into "item_name" from array_schema:

```
<?php
    $apikey = "X";
    $steamid = $steamprofile['steamid'];
    $url_inv = "http://api.steampowered.com/IEconItems_730/GetPlayerItems/v0001/?language=en?key=". $apikey . "&steamid=" . $steamid . "&format=json";
    $url_schema = "http://git.optf2.com/schema-tracking/plain/Counter%20Strike%20Global%20Offensive%20Schema?h=counterstrikeglobaloffensive";
    $array_inv_raw = file_get_contents($url_inv);
    $array_schema_raw = file_get_contents($url_schema);

    $array_inv = json_decode($array_inv_raw,true);
    $array_schema = json_decode($array_schema_raw,true);

    foreach($array_inv['result']['items'] as $item){
        foreach($array_schema['result']['items'] as $schemaItem){
            if($item['defindex'] == $schemaItem['defindex']){
                echo $schemaItem['item_name'].'<br />';
                break;
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

But it's resulting in these errors:

> Warning:
>   file_get_contents(http://api.steampowered.com/IEconItems_730/GetPlayerItems/v0001/?language=en?key=x&steamid=76561198037897388&format=json):
>   failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden in
>   /home/kartm/public_html/scripts/inv.php on line 6
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   /home/kartm/public_html/scripts/inv.php on line 12

The urls:
[array_inv](https://pastebin.com/Z97E1eaY)
[array_schema](http://tny.cz/7ab9eaaf)

I can't find any mistakes. Can you tell me what's wrong with this code?

Comment: array_inv: http://tny.cz/55e2b83a and array_schema: http://tny.cz/7ab9eaaf

Comment: read the error message - you're not allowed to fetch that url. since you're not fetching anything, you have no data to decode nor any array to loop on. Never ever assume an operation with an outside resource succeeded. Always check for failure and treat success as a pleasant surprise.

Comment: The problem was _?language=en_, I just had to remove it. Solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These errors were caused by a typo in a url:

```
http://api.steampowered.com/IEconItems_730/GetPlayerItems/v0001/?language=en?key=x&steamid=76561198037897388&format=json
```

It should have been **&** key=x instead of ?key=x.

file_get_contents couldn't fetch the url, thus the foreach had an invalid, empty argument.